# Updating Firebase core from version 16 to 17 causing compilaton error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, androidx

In my project I use Firebase analytics. After I updated in gradle its version from

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
```

I got compile error

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/josefvancura/Desktop/Programing/Android/PepaApps/Dochazka/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2663: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/josefvancura/Desktop/Programing/Android/PepaApps/Dochazka/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2663: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
   compileSdkVersion 27    // Android 8.1.

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cz.vancura.dochazka"
    minSdkVersion 21        // Android 5.0
    targetSdkVersion 27     // android 8.1
    versionCode 11          // vzdy plus 1
    versionName "5.5"
}

signingConfigs {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "buildTime", "new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L)"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "buildTime", "new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L)"
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

  // update to version 17 - compile error, keep 16.0.7
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

  implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
  implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

  implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
  implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
  androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
  androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [official release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

> Warning: This release is a MAJOR version update and breaking change.
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:

Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.

You have to change the `compileSdkVersion` to 28 and to migrate to androidx library.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

Also you can check the [`fontVariationSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings) attribute.
It was added in api level 28.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the compileSdkVersion to: `compileSdkVersion 28`

Comment: this will return another error ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-66:15 to override.

Comment: @JosefVancura This error is related to androidx migration required by the new firebase libraries. Check the release notes described in the answer below and the steps to follow to fix it.